# batch script to list local hard drives and then do a dir command on each drive

Tags: windows, batch

I tried to make a script following this topic

"batch script to find drive letter of a mounted device"

With help of one stackoverflow user we got the script running.

This is the script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

>"fud_india.com_%computername%.txt" 2>nul (
    for /f "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (
        for %%c in (%%b) do vol %%~dc && dir /s /d "%%~dc\hurrdurr.txt"
    )
)
```

but there is a problem when floppy drive si present (script dropping error window). Is there any way to exclude floppy from the script?

Thank you!

Comment: Since you were successful in getting help as [so], curious why are you asking this question here? Seems it would still be appropriate (and on topic) to ask in the place you were helped with the script in the first place.

Comment: I was told to ask here by the man that helped me :)

Comment: Rather than link to the other question, please ask your question as if the other one doesn't exist, explaining what you have tried and need, including sharing your script. Expecting us to go to another site to try to make sense of what you need will not result in any help.

Comment: I thougt these sites are part of one site, so i didnt think that i need to ask this question again, so i linked stackoverflow topic.. no problem i can ask as a totally new question, but what's the point in redoing stuff already done :)

Comment: Linking so you don't have to explain your question again is not acceptable. Cut and paste is a fantastic tool to save the effort of retyping :). Also, I would suggest you read ***[ask]***. Using this site as intended will produce better results.

Comment: No problem, i will re-ask completely :)